# messed up installation of python modules in venv and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, module, python-venv

I think I messed up the installation of python modules. For a coding course I had to create a venv and install some modules as I was instructed. The problem is now that I think I opened Jupyter Notebook within that venv and since that everything is messed up. Jupyter cant import modules anymore which I have. So I tried to fix it and then Jupyter did not even show the folders on my laptop anymore. This command: `ln -s /opt/homebrew/share/jupyter/ /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/share/jupyter` then fixed this last problem, but what remains is the problem with the modules. I also checked it in Pycharm and Kate, and also there modules cant be imported.

Before the venv Jupyter Notebook worked just fine, was able to import all modules I had and also showed all folders.

What is the best way to go about this? Is there a clean way to get rid of venv, python, jupyter, etc and start back at the download of python and reinstallation? I dont mind these documents being deleted. At this point I'm also considering saving the most important files and setting up my laptop newly.

I'm on MacOS Monterey 12.2 with an M1 chip.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to use homebrew you can uninstall packages with `brew uninstall <package-name>` but unless you messed up some of the path variables in the os you should be good with just deleting the venv folder and creating a new venv. If that is not helping feel free to remove jupyter, venv but be carefull with reinstalling python or pip since this can affect the os.

Comment: yes thanks it worked